# Pointing to a reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

So I am trying to understand pointers and references.

Lets say we have the following:

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = &val;
```

Why is that not the same as simply pointing to val like this:

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = val;
```

Comment: The second one should at the very least emit a big fat warning telling you it's not a good idea, if not an error. This post also has nothing to do with references as it is.

Comment: Your code doesn't have references, at least not in the C++ sense of the word.

Comment: The problem is that `&` has several meanings in `C++`. In your example it means *address of* and it returns a pointer. Nothing in your example uses *references*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither one of your two examples contains a pointer to reference:

- The first example has a pointer to `int`, properly initialized using the *address-of* operator `&`
- The second example has a pointer to `int`, improperly initialized to the *value* of `val` itself

Generally, you do not assign values to pointers directly: normally, you want an address-of operator, an implicit pointer conversion, or some pointer arithmetic. Although assigning a well-known address on specific hardware is also possible, compiler toolchains often provide ways to keep this outside of your program. Hence, if you see an assignment `int *ip = 100` it's almost certainly incorrect.

If you want a reference, declare it like this:

```
int val = 100;
int &ref = val;
```

Now you can make a pointer to that reference, like this:

```
int *ipRef = &ref;
```

Since `ref` represents an alias for `val`, `ipRef` would have the same value as `ip` from your example ([demo](http://ideone.com/U31BqI)).

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to understand why they are not the-same if you do this your self.

```
int val = 100;
cout<<val<<endl;
```

You shoud get **100** as output.

Now try:

```
int val = 100;
cout<<&val<<endl;
```

You should get a **0x7ffc201cab0c**   or something similar as the outout.
If you access `val`  **with** the "&", you are accessing the memory address of it.

If you access `val`  **without** the "&", you are accessing the value of it.

Therefore if you do

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = val;
```

you will should get a **warning** or an **error** but assuming that you want to see it compile so you can figure out what would happen, this is what it you should do:

```
int val = 100;
int *ip;
*ip = val;
```

This is **the-same** as the previous code except that it will **compile**. You are creating a pointer and assigning a value to the pointer instead of assigning a memory address to it. The code is valid but has a **run-time** **error**. The pointer `ip` is NOT pointing anywhere before you assigned value to it.

To make it work properly, you can do:

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = new int;
*ip = val;
```

Now, you have a pointer with a memory address. The value of that pointer is `val` which is 100. That's the value **NOT** the memory address.

To conclude this, pointer must be initialized or it will have undefined behavior or even crash. You use the **ref** sign (**&**) or the `new` keyword to initialize pointers then you can assign assign values to it.

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = new int; //Create a new pointer and initilize it with a new memory address
*ip = val; //Assign the value from val(100) to the pointer
```

**OR**

```
int val = 100;
int *ip = &val; //Create a new pointer and initialize it by making it point to existing address of **val**


*ip = 200; //change the value in the **memory addresss to **200**
```

Now **val** changes to **200** too.

```
int otherValue = 500;
*ip = otherValue ; //change the value in the **memory address** to 500
```

Now **val** changes to **500** too.

**CHANGE MEMORY ADDRESS WHERE ip IS POINTING**

You can also change the memory address anytime.
Lets make p point to otherValue.

```
*ip = &otherValue; //Point p to otherValue memory address not value
*ip = 5; //Change the value of p to 5(no memory address change)
```

Now `otherValue` has **5** as the value. `p` points to `otherValue` **memory address**.

Answer (score 0):

**val** is an `integer`, so you can not assign an **int** to a pointer that points to an int because is not the valid value, you will need the address (obtained with the & operator)

Answer (score 0):

Because pointers and integers are different data types.

> ```
> int *ip = &val;
> ```

This initialises one `int*` with another `int*` (the value obtained by taking the address of `val`).

> ```
> int *ip = val;
> ```

This is an attempt to initialise an `int*` with an `int`, which is not allowed.

Note that your code examples do not contain any references.

Comment: And if you force the compiler to go through with that by saying `int *ip = (int *)val;` you will get a pointer that points to address 100 in memory, which will likely just break when you try to reference it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Yes, you can do a lot of dangerous stuff by shutting up the compiler with a cast, especially an ugly C-style cast.